# jqModal iframe issue

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jqmodal

I have a asp.net page (page1.aspx), inside that I have a iframe, Inside the iframe I am loading another page(page2.aspx). Inside that page(page2.aspx) I have a button. When I click on that button jqModal pops up. It comes up covering the iframe which is in page2.aspx. How can i make the jqModal div to allocate parent page(page1.aspx) full space.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have to pass through the identifier for the parent page all the way through to the jqModal div and use that as the anchor point.